# How to join table with selective duplicate records? (oracle10g)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

How can I create an **ORACLE** query for the following requirement?

The question is If same ID is existed in some of SQL results, how can I get the record of that ID which Name is not blank or NULL.

```
Pattern(1)
SQL1 => RESULT1 =>    ID     NAME
                     -----  ------
                      001
                      002
                      003
```

SQL2 => RESULT2 =>    ID     NAME
                     -----  ------
                      003    NAME1

SQL3 => RESULT3 =>    ID     NAME
                     -----  ------
                      003    NAME2

```
Pattern(2)
SQL1 => RESULT1 =>    ID     NAME
                     -----  ------
                      001
                      002
                      003    NAME1
```

SQL2 => RESULT2 =>    ID     NAME
                     -----  ------
                      003

SQL3 => RESULT3 =>    ID     NAME
                     -----  ------
                      003    NAME2

```
Pattern(3)
SQL1 => RESULT1 =>    ID     NAME
                     -----  ------
                      001
                      002
                      003
```

SQL2 => RESULT2 =>    ID     NAME
                     -----  ------
                      003    NAME1
                      003    NAME2

SQL3 => RESULT3 =>    ID     NAME
                     -----  ------

How can I join these 3 results to become the following result?

```
                      ID     NAME
                     -----  ------
                      001
                      002
                      003    NAME1
                      003    NAME2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This working for your scenario

```
with tbl(id,name) as
(query1 
 union all
query2
 union all
query 3
)
select * From tbl where name is null
 and id not in
    (select id from tbl where name is not null)
union all
select * from tbl where name is not null
```

I have created sample example

```
with tbl(id,name) as
(select 1,null from dual union all
select 2,null from dual union all
select 3,null from dual union all
select 3,'NAME1' from dual union all
select 3,'NAME2' from dual)

select * From tbl where name is null
 and id not in
    (select id from tbl where name is not null)
union all
select * from tbl where name is not null
```

Output

```
id  name
---------
1   
2   
3   NAME1
3   NAME2
```

Comment: Thank you for your response bro!

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to `UNION` together the `SQL2` and `SQL3` tables, and then join this result back to `SQL1`:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.NAME
FROM SQL1 t1 LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT ID, NAME
    FROM SQL2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, NAME
    FROM SQL3
) t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.ID
```

Comment: Thank you bro. Sorry for my misleading question. The results of each sql may be vary. I have updated the question. The question is If same ID is existed in some of SQL results, how can I get the record of that ID which Name is not blank or NULL.

Comment: Your question is now unclear.  Please update again showing sample _tables_ (not diagrams) for input and the expected output.